# WebFaultException not handled in user code

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I am using WCF REST Service (4.0) to expose JSON API ..but not getting my `WebFaultException` to work.

I have following in my method:

```
        if (!int.TryParse(Id, out idValue))
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>(string.Format(WebExceptionMessages.NotIntegerAsParameter),
                                                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

and when i try to call the service from fiddler i always receive the same error message:

[image: Error when debugged]

I have been trying to search for a solution for some time now...please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebFaultException` is working properly - the error message in Visual Studio is just telling you that it wasn't handled - that's the expected behavior. Visual Studio debugger will tell you it's unhandled since you didn't trap the error via try/catch. See [related MSDN blog regarding `WebFaultException` usage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/21/error-handling-in-wcf-webhttp-services-with-webfaultexception.aspx).

Comment: this was is..no I feel stupid. I dag checked out ties post you mentioned. Never ran trough the code after debugging message...

Now i get the correct response :)